# Javascript context for below code

Tags: javascript, scope, apply

```
Array.prototype.max = function() {
return Math.max.apply(null, this); // <-- passing null as the context
//return Math.max.apply(this, this); 
};

var max = [1, 2, 3].max();
```

In the above code, both the return statements return the same thing, the only difference is the context. Please explain both the null and this contect.

In the below code, is there a way to alert uppercase "c" using the above way

```
string.prototype.maxc = function() {
// what is the loc to be put here
};
var cw  = "c".maxc();
alert(cw);
```

Comment: `var comment = 'strings have a built in'.toUpperCase();`

Comment: That is right! but what about the way i asked to alert it?

Comment: alert('c'.toUpperCase());

Answer (score 1):

`Math.max` doesn't need a context, all it needs is a bunch of numbers as arguments.

It doesn't matter what context is passed, or what `this` is inside the `Math.max` function, the only reason `apply` is used is because it accepts an array of arguments, and it's the same as doing

```
Math.max(1, 2, 3);
// or
Math.max.apply('anything', [1, 2, 3]);
```

---

As for alerting uppercase

```
alert( "c".toUpperCase() );
```

Comment: @Barmar - I think we often do, and we're usually correct ;)

Comment: Thanks, 2nd question any idea?

Comment: Sure, like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/yk1cLgL8/**, but why would you do that ?

Comment: Yea, that is the straight forward way, but what about the tricky way to get the answer? Please see the call in my question.

Comment: Did you look at the fiddle I  posted in the comment, and isn't that what you wanted ?

Comment: @user3763367 what are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

`Math.max()` takes the values as regular arguments, it doesn't use its context.  You can put anything as the first argument to `apply()` in this case, `null` is just a convenient placeholder. E.g. you could write:

```
return Math.max.apply("no context needed", this);
```

For the second question, you would write:

```
string.prototype.maxc = function() {
    return this.toUpperCase();
};
```

Comment: Thanks, 2nd question any idea?

Comment: As others have said, your second function is just equivalent to `string.prototype.toUpperCase`.